# Automatically upload photos to a particular Google Photos album

Tags: python, google-api, backup, photos, google-photos

I'm trying to automatically upload JPG photo files from a particular directory on my computer to a particular album on Google Photos. I'd like the photos to periodically get pushed up to Google Photos (every day or so is frequent enough). Google Photos Backup *almost* does what I want, but it just uploads the files -- it doesn't put them into a particular [pre-existing] album on Google Photos. It's possible that I can somehow use Google Drive and a simple cron job for this, although I don't know how. I am also considering using the Picassa Web Albums API, but that feels overkill and I'd like to avoid that work unless it's necessary. Are there any straightforward solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

As you said that *Google Photo Backup* do the (upload) job, in my opinion the best way then is to use directly a *Google Apps Script* stored inside your *Google Drive* (running periodicaly) in order to push each new detected pictures inside a particular album.

If you need relative documentation, you may take a look at the [album class](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/picasa-services/album) documentation and also https://developers.google.com/apps-script/

If you need to use an other language to do the job (python, js, etc...) please specify which one and give us also more precision. (mac / windows / linux)

Comment: I would like to upload photos to album using Python. Is it possible? Probably on mac.

Comment: Take a look here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation to start, I just add python tag

Answer (score 0):

Use IFTTT for this. Google Photos channel perfectly fits for this purpose. https://ifttt.com/applets/DMgPS2uZ-back-up-new-android-photos-you-take-to-google-photos